# How to make an object inside a function and return it to main() without the destructor delete it in c++?

Tags: c++, object, dynamically-generated

I have this class:

```
class foo{

public:
    foo();
    foo(const int& var);
    foo(const foo& var);
    ~foo();

    foo retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2);

private:
    int a;
    char* x;

};
```

and this meber function:

```
foo foo::retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2){

    //Make somehow a foo object,
    //lets name it 'result'

    result.a = var1.a + var2.a;

    return (result);
}
```

**I want to do this in main:**

```
main(){

    foo a, b;
    foo* c;

    a.a = 1;
    b.a = 2;

    c = retSumOf(a, b);

    cout << "sum =" << c->a;

}
```

**without to invoke the (overloaded) copy constructor!**

**Is there a way in C++ to create an object dynamically from a function and return his address? Without the constructor to delete it at the end of the invocation of retSumOf()?**

Comment: Sure, allocate it with new and wrap it in a shared_ptr or unique_ptr or similar.  I don't think there's any advantage to doing so, though, unless the object is really huge or you are using polymorphism.

Comment: By the way, why is `retSumOf` a member function, and why are you trying to call it like a free function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the function as follows:

```
foo* foo::retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2){

    //Make somehow a foo object,
    //lets name it 'result'
    foo* result = new foo();

    result->a = var1.a + var2.a;

    return (result);
}
```

Comment: @SebastianRedl Bad yes but doable ... the user asked how he can do this. He didn't ask if that is the best way.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not a fan of just answering a question when it's obviously the wrong thing to do.

Comment: OK @SebastianRedl ... I will accept it if you can promise that you haven't ever created a function of similar type in your programming life :-)

Comment: @SebastianRedl why this is a bad technique? Is there any logical error?
@Trifon the `result = new foo();` you write is correct? Don't you need to declare also the type of the result? For example `foo result = new foo();` ?

Comment: I promise. I have returned smart pointers, but never since I was a complete beginner have I returned a raw pointer in C++ unless there was an existing API contract forcing me to.

Comment: @MinimalTech To begin with, if you adjust your function this way, then you have to remember to `delete` the object in `main`. Basically, any time you have to deal with `delete` in anything but specialized code, you're too low level. This is the modern C++ way of doing things. It's easy to reason about. It's unlikely to have dangling pointers/references or leaks. Use value semantics when you can, and smart pointers when you can't. The problem of `retSumOf` taking two references and returning a pointer is fundamentally that it's completely unintuitive.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I understand it. You are also true but i think Trifon has the exact answer of what I ask. Thank you for your advices! As an adorer of pure C, I will use this dirty raw pointers and I promise to be careful! :)

Answer (score 5):

Why?

Yes, you can return a (smart) pointer, like Jeremy says, but why would you do that? Why not instead correctly implement the copy and move functions? You already have a constructor; by the rule of five you should implement the other four functions anyway, or suppress them.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways, first:

You can use the return value as an argument:

```
void foo::computeSumOf(foo & result, const foo& var1, const foo& var2) ...
```

Another way is to take advantage of the [RVO optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

```
foo foo::retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2)
{
    return foo(var1.a + var2.a);
}
//...
foo x = someFoo.retuSomOf(a,b);
```

Third (if you can use c++ 11) you can use write move constructor and assignment to avoid copy constructor. By doing this you can optimize the unnecessary copy of members and just "move" the memory from one instance to another . You can find more info [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html).

```
class foo{
public:
    foo(foo && rValue) { ... };
    foo& operator = (foo && rValue) { ... };
    ...
};
foo foo::retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2){
    foo result;
    //same code
    return result;
}
```

Lastly, you can use [shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) or other smart pointers (like [intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html))

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> foo::retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2){
    std::shared_ptr<foo> result = new foo;
    result->a = ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to return `std::move(result)`? That inhibits NRVO.

Comment: Never `std::move` when returning a local object. It inhibits RVO, and doesn't gain you anything, because returning of local objects happens by moving by default.

Comment: @0x499602D2 i provided `std::move` example because if `foo` class does special things with that `x` member i'm not sure how the compiler can move that.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl are you suggesting to remove `std::move(result)` and just override the rvalue constructor ?

Comment: @Raxvan Yes. Just `return result;` will call the move constructor if it's available, and if it's not completely optimized away by NRVO. `return std::move(result);` will call the move constructor too, but it will never be optimized away.

Answer (score 1):

You could either declare it as static:

`static myClass objName;`

or use new (preferred):

```
myClass* objName = new myClass;    
return objName
```

If you use the second method, you need to modify your function to return a pointer, rather than an object.

Comment: Raw pointer. Bad. Static object with unexpected sharing. Worse.

Comment: Raw pointer are not always bad. Static object, I grant you is mostly evil.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the value from the function as a reference to `foo` and save it in a `const foo&`. The const-reference will prolong the lifespan of the `foo` instance to the lifespan of the variable.

```
foo& foo::retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2)
...
const foo& c = retSumOf(a, b);
```

**EDIT**

Turns out this does not work: http://ideone.com/WM3bIe

Comment: This is just inviting a dangling reference, especially if you don't show the code of `retSumOf`.

Comment: Returning a reference won't prolong the lifetime of a local variable. This will give a dangling reference, and undefined behaviour if you use it.

Comment: http://ideone.com/WM3bIe Ok... Thank you for correcting me before I go blow something up.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
class foo
{
    ...
    friend foo retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2);
    ...
};

foo retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2);
{
    foo result;
    result.a = var1.a + var2.a;

    return (result);
}
```

and **enable compiler optimization**.
Since there's only one return statement in your function, and `result` is local, the compiler will create it on the stack in the place of the return value, avoiding the copy.

No need to worry about that. (and yes, no need to call "move").

If you want a more "functional" approach, give to `foo` a constructor that defines the member values and use accordngly:

```
class foo
{
  // you existing code andd ...

  foo(int i, const char* s) :a(i), x(s) 
  {}
};
```

so that you can do

```
foo retSumOf(const foo& var1, const foo& var2)
{  return foo(var1.a + var1.b, nullptr); }
```

It it even make sense, you can name `retSumOf` just `operator+` and have `c = a+b`;

In any case, avoid to have `c` as a naked pointer: it will never be clear who has to delete the received object. It only needs to be a value.

Don't ever use char* as a member: it is not clear who owns the data after an assignment or a copy. Use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if my answer is right but it actually seems to work all the time for me:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() {std::cout<<"HEY!";}
        ~Foo() {}
};


Foo&& GetFoo()
{
    return std::move(Foo());
}


int main()
{
    GetFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

I usually just move an object created within a function.. Just so that I can avoid pointers as much as possible.. Otherwise I'd use a Smart pointer but the above is what I normally do.

Comment: This is a dangling reference and using the return value of `GetFoo` in any way is therefore undefined behavior. You will have to go back to all your code and fix it. Any sensible compiler warns you about this if you just turn the warnings on. Also, the `std::move` there is redundant.

Comment: Why is it dangling? Well if Foo is actually properly constructed with RAII and everything (move, copy, etc), is it still dangling?..

Comment: The temporary object you're creating goes away as the return statement finishes - even before the function ends. Yet you still give out a reference. And yes, it doesn't matter how properly `Foo` is written. The problem is returning a reference to a local object.